# Two RAM modules with different frequencies

Tags: memory, ramdisk, dell-studio

I have a Dell laptop which I bought 3 years ago. its a First gen i7 and its absolutely working fine. Since i use softwares like Photoshop Illustrator and Dreamweaver. I want to upgrade the RAM. I called  Dell Care and asked them for an additional 4GB.

They said they have a 4GB DDR3 which is 1333MHz and the one installed in my laptop is 2GB 10xx Mhrtz. He said i will have to replace the one I have with the new one and both of them wont work together.

Is there any way I can make them work together or its better to discard the old RAM ?

Comment: What is the model of your laptop? 4GB DIMMs are around [$20](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231266). I'd just throw out the old one. If your laptop can take it, get two 4GB DIMMs.

Comment: its a Studio 17

Comment: Yeah, then definitely get two 4GB DIMMs for $40 or so and have 8GB at full speed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how can i make sure its compatible with my laptop ? lol the guy on call took 5mins to make sure the ram is compatible or not to what they have in stock. And holy crap he said it will cost 160$ for 8GB RAM

Comment: If you're that worried about it, buy from a vendor that [guarantees compatability](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=F20244E8A5CA7304).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks a lot :D now i have to see how to get it shipped to India :P

Answer (score 1):

In your case the 1333MHz RAM will be run with 1066MHz.

Comment: i would not need to discard the 2gb ? or will the new one run at the lower speed ?

Comment: You can keep it for 6GB, but you'll lose the benefit of dual-channel memory because your channels will be unbalanced.

Comment: yes, the new RAM runs slower, but more RAM is better than having a slightly faster RAM when you do Photoshop.